# How to remove a marker from a Leaflet map?

Tags: leaflet, maps, nominatim, vue.js

I'm currently making a website where I'm using Leaflet 1.7.1 and Nominatim API and VueJS 3 and I'm trying to delete the marker after I search an address. When I search the address the first time everything works fine but if I search another address again, the first maker stays on the map.

How can I fix this?
I'm a beginner.
[image]
Here's my code :

```
<template>
<div class="home">
      <div id="map">
      </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

```
<script>
import 'leaflet-defaulticon-compatibility/dist/leaflet-defaulticon-compatibility.webpack.css'; 
import 'leaflet-defaulticon-compatibility';
import * as L from 'leaflet';
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';

import places from "../components/places.js";

import axios from "axios";
export default {
  name: "carte",
  components: {
  },
  data ()  {
        return {
            adresse: '133 Boulevard Maxime Gorki,Stains',
            loading: false,
            wait: false,
            resultats: [],
            erreur: false,
            //map: null,
            latitude: '45', // positionnement par defaut
            longitude: '2', // positionnement par defaut
            marker: {},
      
    },
    mounted() { /* Code to run when app is mounted */ 
        this.initMap(this.latitude, this.longitude); 
    },
    watch: {
        /* check variables in real time */
        //remove marker
        adresse: function() {
            // this.wait = true;
            // this.map.remove(marker); 
            // this.map.removeLayer(marker);
            console.log('TEST SUPP MARKER');
          },
          longitude: function() {
            console.log('WATCHER : mise à jour de longitude');
          }
      
    },
    methods: {
        getLocation: function () {
                console.log('METHOD : getLocation');
                // vm = this;
            axios.get('https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q='+encodeURIComponent(this.adresse)+'&format=json&polygon=1&addressdetails=1&limit=1')
            .then(response => {
                this.loading = false;
                // this.resultats = response.data;
                this.latitude = response.data[0].lat;
                this.longitude = response.data[0].lon;
                
                                // then update map
                this.updateMap(this.latitude,this.longitude);
                 
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
                this.erreur = true
            })
            .finally(() => {
                this.loading = false;
            })
        },        
        initMap: function (lat,lon) {
        console.log('METHOD : initMap');

            this.map = L.map('map').setView([lat,lon],5);
              
                this.tileLayer = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                  minZoom: 4,
                  maxZoom: 19,
                  zoomControl: false,
                  attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                }).addTo(this.map);
                
                L.control.scale({
                  metric: true,
                  imperial: false,
                  position: 'bottomleft'
                }).addTo(this.map);

                this.map.zoomControl.remove();
                L.control.zoom({
                    position: 'bottomright'
                }).addTo(this.map);
        },
        locatorButtonPressed: function(){
          this.map.locate({setView: true, maxZoom: 23});
      }, 
        // centre la carte avec les nouvelles coordonnées / 
        
        updateMap: function (lat,lon) {
          var marker = this.marker;
          console.log('METHOD : updateMap');
          const defaultMarker = 'data:image/png;base64,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';
          const defaultMarkerShadow = 'data:image/png;base64,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';

            var defaultIcon = new L.Icon({
                iconUrl: defaultMarker,
                shadowUrl: defaultMarkerShadow,
                iconSize: [25, 40],
                iconAnchor: [10, 40],
                popupAnchor:  [3, -40]
            });

            if (typeof marker !== "undefined") {
                this.map.removeLayer(marker);
            };
                console.log('etape 2');
                // init du marker
                  marker = new L.marker([lat,lon], { icon: defaultIcon }).addTo(this.map).bindPopup("Votre Recherche !");
                  this.map.addLayer(marker)
                        this.map.setView([lat,lon], 23);   
        },
```

Comment: Hey Kadir thanks for answering I just tried you proposition and it didn't worked :/ I can search an adress but the marker stay on the map everytime I search an adress

Comment: Classic scope issue - `var marker` exists only in the `updateMap` callback, so it'll start with a value of `undefined` each time the callback runs. Hoist it up. Read up on the scope of variables.

Comment: Hi Ivan, I understand what my issue is now but whereever I put the var maker, it still gives  me an error, do you have any recommandation pls on where to put the var marker ?

Comment: ...and now you're reading from `this.marker` but are never writing a value there.

Comment: Okay so I added a "marker {}; " in the data to store all the marker. In the update function I have a "var marker = this.marker" so it does take the data in the "marker {}; " right ? and then when it's "!==undefiend " it should remove the marker right ?
It still doesn't work the icon stay after every search I make :/